# pyarrow write_to_dataset with partition_cols drops pandas index info

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I am trying to read / write partitioned pandas datasets. A simple example is this:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 2), index=pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', periods=1000))
df['__partition'] = df.index.year
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)

data_path_with_partitions = 'with_partitions.parquet'
pq.write_to_dataset(table, root_path=data_path_with_partitions, partition_cols=['__partition'])
```

However, when I read this dataset

```
table_read_with_partitions = pq.read_table(data_path_with_partitions, use_pandas_metadata=True)
df_read_with_partitions = table_read_with_partitions.to_pandas()
```

The index is not set on the object, but instead a new column `'__index_level_0__'` has appeared.

```
            0 __index_level_0__ __partition
0   -0.318132        2000-01-01        2000
1    1.190233        2000-01-02        2000
2    1.504262        2000-01-03        2000
3   -1.627234        2000-01-04        2000
4   -0.735535        2000-01-05        2000
..        ...               ...         ...
995 -0.695556        2002-09-22        2002
996  1.117392        2002-09-23        2002
997  1.072292        2002-09-24        2002
998  0.881316        2002-09-25        2002
999 -0.134482        2002-09-26        2002

[1000 rows x 3 columns]
```

If I do exactly the same process, but without setting `partition_cols=` in the `write_to_dataset`, it all works as expected:

```
data_path_without_partitions = 'without_partitions.parquet'
pq.write_to_dataset(table, root_path=data_path_without_partitions)

table_read_without_partitions = pq.read_table(data_path_without_partitions, use_pandas_metadata=True)
df_read_without_partitions = table_read_without_partitions.to_pandas()
```

And the output of `df_read_without_partitions` becomes

```
                   0  __partition
2000-01-01 -0.318132         2000
2000-01-02  1.190233         2000
2000-01-03  1.504262         2000
2000-01-04 -1.627234         2000
2000-01-05 -0.735535         2000
...              ...          ...
2002-09-22 -0.695556         2002
2002-09-23  1.117392         2002
2002-09-24  1.072292         2002
2002-09-25  0.881316         2002
2002-09-26 -0.134482         2002

[1000 rows x 2 columns]
```

but of course without actually having a partitioned dataset.

It seems this is due to the pandas index_columns schema not being written in the partition case: `table_read_with_partitions.schema` contains no index columns

```
0: double
  -- field metadata --
  PARQUET:field_id: '1'
__index_level_0__: timestamp[us]
  -- field metadata --
  PARQUET:field_id: '2'
__partition: dictionary<values=int64, indices=int32, ordered=0>
-- schema metadata --
pandas: '{"index_columns": [], "column_indexes": [], "columns": [{"name":' + 322
```

but `table_read_without_partitions.metadata` has the index values set.

```
0: double
  -- field metadata --
  PARQUET:field_id: '1'
__partition: int64
  -- field metadata --
  PARQUET:field_id: '2'
__index_level_0__: timestamp[us]
  -- field metadata --
  PARQUET:field_id: '3'
-- schema metadata --
pandas: '{"index_columns": ["__index_level_0__"], "column_indexes": [{"na' + 553
```

Are there any parameters / settings I'm missing when reading / writing the parquet files?

Comment: There is a `preserve_index` parameter in Table.from_pandas() that might help (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html).

Comment: `preserve_index` defaults to True (except for the details around how a RangeIndex would be stored, which don't apply here), so that doesn't help.